Howto configure Gmail as Email-to-Case Outbound Service in Salesforce?
I'm trying to configure Gmail as an External Service in the Email-to-Case configuration. When trying to "Connect to Gmail' I'm getting the following message in Gmail: (I am an Account admin)
This app is blocked
This app tried to access sensitive info in your Google Account. To keep your account safe, Google blocked this access.
I was suggested to go to the Gmail admin console to Security --> Access and data control --> API controls, and 'Add App' . I tried to Add Salesforce but it doesn't help.
Any chance someone already went through this configuration successfully and can share some guidance?
Openend a Case with Salesforce, without any results so far

OK, Sorted:
As an account admin, navigate to Security --> Access and data control --> API controls. Click Manage third-party app access and Add app, select OAuth App Name or Client ID, and search for Salesforce. Make sure to select the Salesforce that is circled in the screenshot. If you previously selected another Salesforce app then make sure to Block it.
Salesforce App List
